# .htaccess mod rewrite for product id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Evening guys,

I have been attempting to get mod rewrite working for product id's and name's but I am having no luck at all. I have tried searching here on SO but there are no clear explanations.

This is for my ecommerce demo located http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/store

**Example URL:** http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/product_page?id=3name=Bed

I want: http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/product_page?id=3name=Bed

to be http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/3-Bed

My URL is structured as follows:

```html
<a href='product_page?id=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["product_id"].'name='.$product_array[$key]["product_name"]; ?>' id='product_links'><?php  echo '<div id="product_image"><img src="images/'. $product_array[$key]["image"] . '"></div>' ?> </a>
```

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess (I know the first few code entries work because I have removed .php and .html from files):

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9])-([A-Z]+)$ product_page?id=$1name=$2  [NC,L]
```

**Question: Due to me having /ecommerce/ included in my URL is the above setup correctly?**

If not, can anyone help assist me in writing this correctly?

Thanks.
Stan.

Comment: "I have tried searching here on SO but there are no clear explanations." hmmm, well there certainly are, but more important is: why would you research answers on SO instead of reading the documentation of the tool you use? The documentation of the apache http server's modules is of very high quality and comes with really good examples...

Comment: For the specific issue you raise in your question: would you mind adding to the question _where_ in the server side file system hierarchy you placed that dynamic configuration file you use?

Comment: I've researched on Google / YouTube / SO and have trialled loads of variations of code. My question in bold is something that I think is effecting how it works. This is why I have asked the community here on SO.  Each answer I have found on SO has variations of how the code is written.EDIT: I have placed the .htaccess file at both / and /ecommerce/

Comment: Once more: apparently you did not even think of reading the documentation... _why now_ ? All this is not about trying as many code examples as possible, but about _understanding_ how the tool you are using actually works.

Comment: I know how the code is written hence what I have above, I have attempted to do it based on my understanding. Is this the correct guide http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Please use the _current_ versions documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ & http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yeah it makes no sense. Doesnt explain how to utilise dynamic data in a URL

Comment: Hm, strange. I always found my answers in there. But maybe you could at least answer to my question in my second comment? And tell me what you refer to by "dynamic data" if not HTTP GET arguments, since those definitely are covered in the documentation?

Comment: I placed the .htaccess file http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/(here) and http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/(here) as i wasnt sure which was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following rules to adjust URLs according to the parameters:

RewriteRule ^ecommerce/product/(.*)$ ./ecommerce/product?id=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ecommerce/category/(.*)$ ./ecommerce/category_page?category_name=$1 [L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible setups, I expect this to be the one *most likely* making sense for you (you offered very little information about your situation):

Best is to place such rewriting rules inside the host configuration of your http server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/ecommerce/(\d+)-(\w+)/?$ /ecommerce/product_page?id=$1name=$2 [END]
```

Alternatively you can also use a dynamic configuration file. I then would recommend to place that file inside the `ecommerce` folder and start with something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ecommerce
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)-(\w+)/?$ product_page?id=$1name=$2 [END]
```

For this to work you need to enable the interpretation of dynamic configuration files fist, take a look the the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation for that.

*Note:* in case you receive back an http status 500 (internal server error) with above rules, then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try to replace the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag.

Also, for the sake of precision I want to point out that you need to format the links you send out correctly. You cannot keep the code *creating* the links unchanged and expect the rewriting module to magically alter the literal links you send out.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to write this. 

I have updated the .htaccess and I will read into using the http host config file, certainly. 

I updated my href to id-name (using php variables) but it is 404'ing, I have also used /3-Bed and it still doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Still struggling with this if anyone can help. 

rewrite rule is 

RewriteBase /ecommerce
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)/?$ product_page?id=$1 [END]

Trying to change 
http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/product_page?id=1

to
http://www.peakwebdesigns.co.uk/ecommerce/product/1

**I wish to keep /ecommerce/ in the URL